# Bypass the loading function on PHP generated table when Ajax post request is triggered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, ajaxform

I am trying to do `Ajax` post request without refreshing page in loading php generated table. PHP table is loading without refreshing the page by using `XMLHttprequest` `onload()`. The post request is triggered by using `onclick` button and it is within the php generated table, and then the request is processed via `Ajax` form data serialize. The result is done successfully, but it needed to do double click to override loading function and process the `Ajax` post request. Thus, I come here to ask a question that can I finish the process within single click.

This is my whole code:

```
 <?php
require_once "db_conn.php";

$Host_ID = $_GET['Host_ID'];
$sql = "Select * from Chat_List inner join Chat_Room on Chat_List.Room_ID = Chat_Room. Room_ID 
        where Chat_List.Chat_ID = $Host_ID order By Chat_Room.Update_time DESC";
$row = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Chat_Search.css">
</head>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function ChatRoomSearch(){
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function(e){
    document.getElementById("table3").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    //document.getElementById("Check").trigger("Click");
  }

  xhttp.open("GET", "Chat_Search.php?Host_ID="+Host_ID, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
setInterval(function(){
     ChatRoomSearch(); 
  }, 3000);


</script>
<body>
<?php
$Host_ID = $_GET['Host_ID'];
echo"<script> var Host_ID = '$Host_ID';</script>";
?>

<table id = 'table3' border = 1 cellpadding = 10>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Friend</th>
<th>Message</th>
<th>Room ID</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($row as $row):
?>
<tr>
<td><?php 
    if ($row["Invitor"] != $Host_ID){
        echo $row["Invitor"];
    }else{
        echo $row["Host"];
    }
?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Room_Message"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?></td>
<td>
  <?php
  if ($row["status"] == 'confirm' and $row["Invitor"] == $Host_ID){
  ?>
<form id = "form<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" action="Chat_Room_Confirm.php">
  <input type="text" name="Room_ID" id="Room_ID<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="Room_status" id="Room_status<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="Chat">
  <input type="button" class="myinput" id="myinput<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="Invite" >
  <script>
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   $('#myinput<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').on ('click' ,function(){
      var form = $('#form<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>');
      var Room_ID = $('#Room_ID<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').val();
      var Room_status = $('#Room_status<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').val();
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
         url:form.attr("action"),
         method:"POST",
         data:formData,
         cache:false,
         success:function(){
           alert('Data Send');
         }
      });
   });
   return false;
});
  </script>
</form>
  <?php } ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the below the code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myinput<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').on ('click' ,function(event){
      event.preventDefault();      
      var form = $('#form<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>');
      var Room_ID = $('#Room_ID<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').val();
      var Room_status = $('#Room_status<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>').val();
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
         url:form.attr("action"),
         method:"POST",
         data:formData,
         cache:false,
         success:function(){
           alert('Data Send');
         }
      });
   });
   return false;
});
```

Thank you for everyone looking my question.

Comment: Is the posted script `Chat_search.php`? It's returning an entire HTML page, not just the contents of the table.

Comment: And the first time you load the page, there won't be any `$_GET['Host_ID']`, so you'll get a SQL error.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is script of Chat_search.php. About `$_GET['HOST_ID`], I will enter it into URL to let the script read it since it is just a part of my project. Also, I will consider to use MYSQLI or PDO, thanks for your advice.

Comment: `I will consider to use MYSQLI or PDO`...you're already using mysqli. The point Barmar made is that you need to use it _safely_ and _reliably_ by using prepared statements and parameters instead of how you write queries now (with user input just included directly into the query text).

Comment: Sorry, I make a misunderstanding on Barmar points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of improvement is required in your code.

a) Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query.

b) jQuery code for the same event handling inside the loop is a blunder, don't do that.

c) Until you get `Host_ID` in `$_GET`, don't execute your code.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Chat_Search.css">
</head>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <?php 
        require_once "db_conn.php";
        $Host_ID = 0;
        if(!empty($_GET['Host_ID'])){

            $Host_ID = $_GET['Host_ID'];
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "Select * from Chat_List inner join Chat_Room on Chat_List.Room_ID = Chat_Room. Room_ID 
                    where Chat_List.Chat_ID = ? order By Chat_Room.Update_time DESC");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $Host_ID);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

        ?>
        <table id = 'table3' border = 1 cellpadding = 10>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Friend</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Room ID</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($row["Invitor"] != $Host_ID){
                                echo $row["Invitor"];
                            }else{
                                echo $row["Host"];
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Room_Message"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($row["status"] == 'confirm' and $row["Invitor"] == $Host_ID){?>
                            <form id = "form<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" action="Chat_Room_Confirm.php">
                                <input type="text" name="Room_ID" id="Room_ID<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="text" name="Room_status" id="Room_status<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="Chat">
                                <input type="button" class="myinput" id="myinput<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>" value="Invite" >
                            </form>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
var Host_ID = "<?php echo $Host_ID;?>";
function ChatRoomSearch(){
    if(Host_ID > 0){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(e){
            document.getElementById("table3").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "Chat_Search.php?Host_ID="+Host_ID, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        ChatRoomSearch(); 
    }, 3000);

    $(document).on('click', '.myinput', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).closest('form').attr("action"),
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                alert('Data Send');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```